# How to display multiple models within the same foreach in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreach, many-to-many, join

How to display multiple models within the same foreach when there is a many to many table?

There are 3 tables (`tblProduct, tblCustomer, tblOrder`). `tblOrder` & `tblProduct` are many-to-many, while `tblCustomer` & `tblOrder` are one-to-many.

I want to join these 3 tables and display records related to `OrderNo`.

I have used Entity Framework database-first (so I don't have intermediate table for many to many relationship).

Please help me . I'm new to MVC. Thanks in advance.

These are my tables:

`Product` table:

```
public partial class tblProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tblOrder> tblOrders { get; set; }
}
```

`Customer` table:

```
public partial class tblCustomer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tblOrder> tblOrders { get; set; }
}
```

`Order` table:

```
public partial class tblOrder
{
    {
        this.tblProducts = new HashSet<tblProduct>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SubTotal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> DiscountTotal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Tax { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> NetTotal { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }

    public virtual tblCustomer tblCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblProduct> tblProducts { get; set; }
}
```

View model I created:

```
public class OrderCustomerProductViewModel
{
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Total { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this but I got an error:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var results = (db.tblOrders.Where(l => l.OrderNo == id).Include(c => c.tblCustomer).Include(p => p.tblProducts)
          .Select(v => new OrderCustomerProductViewModel
          {
              OrderNo  = v.OrderNo,
              CustomerName= v.tblCustomer.CustomerName,
              ProductId = v.tblProducts.ProductId, <------ ERROR
              Quantity = v.Quantity,
              UnitPrice = v.tblProducts.UnitPrice,  <------ ERROR
              Discount = v.Discount,
              Total = v.Total,
          })).ToList();

    return View(results);
}
```

This is my `View.cshtml`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr id="rowtest">
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.OrderNo)</td>
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CustomerName)</td>
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ProductId)</td>
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Quantity)</td>
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.tblProductList.uni)</td>
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Discount)</td>
        <td height="100">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Total)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have added this to the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GridViewFuction.Models.ViewModel.OrderCustomerProductViewModel>
```

Error :ICollection doesn't contain a definition for ProductId and UnitPrice

It will be a big help if you can help me.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error do you get?? Please don't just tease us with "there's an error" - please **always** provide all the details about the error you can - after all - we **cannot** see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you have to **TELL US** what this error is!!

Comment: Error:  ICollection doesn't contain a definition for ProductId and UnitPrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are accessing the data is the problem. the line below

```
 ProductId = v.tblProducts.ProductId
```

You have an `int` on one side and a `List<int>` on the other side, so it is in the `UnitPrice`

I don't know how you want to display the model but I will give some options

**With your model the same way use**

```
ProductId = v.tblProducts.First().ProductId
```

**Changing your model to this**

```
public class OrderCustomerProductViewModel
{
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<int> ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<int> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Total { get; set; }
}
```

Then use

```
ProductId = v.tblProducts.Select(m => m.ProductId).ToList()
```

So your result now looks like:

```
var results = (tblOrders.Where(l => l.OrderNo == id)
            .Select(v => new OrderCustomerProductViewModel
            {
                OrderNo = v.OrderNo,
                CustomerName = v.tblCustomer.CustomerName,
                ProductId = v.tblProducts.Select(m => m.ProductId).ToList(),
                Quantity = v.Quantity,
                UnitPrice = v.tblProducts.Select(m => m.UnitPrice).ToList(),
                Discount = v.Discount,
                Total = v.Total,
            })).ToList();
```

What I have above displays single Customer and the customers products, but if you want to display individual customer with individual products and prices, you have to

1. *Assuming each `Order` has a `UnitPrice` and a `Product`*, first get the count of the products and loop through it while creating your model.

**EDIT:**

```
//first create a list of your view model
var resultList = new List<OrderCustomerProductViewModel>();
var results = tblOrders.Where(l => l.OrderNo == id).ToList();
//the above code can be var results = tblOrder.toList(); if you need all orders
//now loop through the results above
foreach (var order in results)
{
    var products = order.tblProducts;
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        resultList.Add(new OrderCustomerProductViewModel
        {
            OrderNo = order.OrderNo,
            CustomerName = order.tblCustomer.CustomerName,
            ProductId = product.ProductId,
            Quantity = order.Quantity,
            UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice,
            Discount = order.Discount,
            Total = order.Total,
        });
    }    
}
//then use the resultList
//NOTE that I went with the above assumption
```

2. *Some `Orders` does not have a `Product` and or `UnitPrice`*, get the one that has the highest count among `Product` and `UnitPrice` and use the count for the loop.

I cannot wirte the whole code here.

Comment: Thank you very much Bosco. I got a rusult.
 But when there are more than one orders for an OrderNo ,
 all the results show in one cell. 
 How can I get more rows for each order.
 For ex :- if there are three orders for an OrderNo,
 there are three ProductId s and UnitPrices .
So I need three rows to be displayed.other data will be repeated, but It's ok. Please help me.
 I'm a beginner to MVC.